# Function Annotations giving error in python?

Tags: python, function, annotations

So I made a function, and wanted to add annotations to it, and the compiler keeps giving me an error:

```
def square_root(x:number, eps:number) -> float:
    pass
```

And the compiler returns this:

```
  File "/Users/albertcalzaretto/Google Drive/CSC148H1/e1/e1a.py", line 1
    def square_root(x, eps) -> float:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've never used function annotations, and I've read several sources about it, and I don't think what I'm doing is wrong.

Comment: what version of Python are you using? Function annotations are only in Python 3

Comment: It should be python 3, is there a way to check with my compiler? Im using eclipse as the IDE, and there's a chance that it's compiling in python 2

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: You're right, thank you! D:

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. You must be using Python 2.x somehow.  [Function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) are only supported in Python 3.x.  If you try to use them in Python 2.x, you will get a `SyntaxError`:

   ```
   >>> def f() -> int:
     File "<stdin>", line 1
       def f() -> int:
               ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   >>>
   ```
2. If `number` is undefined (which I believe it is), then you need to make it a string so that you don't get a `NameError`.  Below is a demonstration:

   ```
   >>> def square_root(x:number, eps:number) -> float:
   ...     pass
   ...
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'number' is not defined
   >>>
   >>> def square_root(x:'number', eps:'number') -> float:
   ...     pass
   ...
   >>>
   ```

Comment: Thanks!  And turns out it was compiling in python 2.7 :/